# Download multiple file in order from JSON

Tags: c#, json, download, uwp

How to download multiple file in order? For example: i have 3 file on json, i want to download the first file, second file, and third file. Because in my code, files downloaded simultaneously, so a smaller file size is completed beforehand (so files are not sequentially). 
And i have a question, how to overcome that successively file directly (no delay time)? Because when you use this code, then there is a delay time of several seconds to download the first file with the next file in one bundle)

My project: [Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4oRSWSS0hKDT3F5NWpQVS1QV0U/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please post any relevant code inside your question. Very few people will be willing to go to a non-Stack-Overflow page, let alone download and unpack a zip file and try to hunt down in your project what exactly you are talking about. Please read about [short, self-contained, correct examples](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You can download files not async but synchronously to be sure which download will be completed first second etc..

Comment: @Jerrak0s: what do you mean by: You can download files not async but synchronously to be sure which download will be completed first second etc? Can give me the code or the sample?

Comment: Why does it matter the order in which they are complete? You could just check to see if all files have downloaded before starting on what ever your next step is in what you are working on. Downloading them one at a time would guarantee the order in which they complete but that's lower performance. Chances are what ever you are trying to do can be done irrespective of the completion order.

Comment: @Joel I need to download the order. Because the project I'm working need to show the downloaded sequentially. How to?

Comment: I still really doubt it is absolutely necessary to download the files in a specific order. If there is something else that is watching for download completion consider downloading to some other location and then copying all the files to a new location once they are all downloaded.

If you must have them complete in a specific order don't start downloading the second file until the first has downloaded. Don't have it donload the third until the second has completed.

Comment: @Joel: The problem is the project that I am working to be downloaded according to the order and I needed that start downloading the second file until the first has downloaded

Comment: How to download  according to the order and I needed that start downloading the second file until the first has downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

What about this synchronously download?

```
var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
var result = client.GetStringAsync("url").Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say that I think that trying to force a completion order is a **really bad idea**. It may hint at code that is not properly handling synchronous operations and it will make an application slower/less responsive. If however you want to continue down what I think to be an unadvisable  pathway you can just not start your next download until your previous one finishes. One example:

```
async void SynchronousDownload()
{
    string[] filesToDownload = new string[] {
        //enter your list of download URLS here
    };
Queue<DownloadOperation> downloadOperationList = new Queue<DownloadOperation>();

BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();

foreach(string fileURL in filesToDownload)
{
    string fileName = fileURL.Substring(fileURL.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    var newFile = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

    var x = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(fileURL), newFile);
    downloadOperationList.Enqueue(x);                
}

do
{
    DownloadOperation d = downloadOperationList.Dequeue();
    await d.StartAsync();
} while (downloadOperationList.Count > 0);
}
```

Chances are you are not using the DownloadManager but something else. The same concepts should apply. In the above I start downloading a file and upon it's completion the next file starts